# Same rank implies same column space

Tags: linear-algebra

True or False? If $X$ and $Y$ are conformable matrices for the product $XY$ and if the rank of $XY$ equals the rank of $X$, then the span of the columns of $XY$ equals the span of the columns of $X$.

If it is true, prove it.

This seems like it can not be true, but I have not yet found a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**True** :
  Note that a column of $XY$ is a linear combination of columns of $X$. Hence $$ {\rm col}\ (XY)\subset {\rm col}\ (X)$$ 
Since rank are same, they are same.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand the correlation between rank and column space.

Comment: It is definition : ${\rm rank}\ (X)={\rm dim}\ {\rm col}\ (X)$